# Python script on EC2 Instance, multiple databases

Tags: python, database, amazon-ec2, pipeline

I have a Python script running on an EC2 instance.  The script ingests data from a particular database, runs some fancy black box stuff, then spits out a table of predicted values back to the original database (fun with sqlalchemy).  Where I'm stuck is:  I now need to replicate that by n number of databases, each with their own credentials.  I need to be able to pass in database parameters from different Redshift databases (each database is for a different customer). I've read a number of posts here and on Medium, but none seem to address this particular use case. Any suggestions, thoughts or ideas are welcome. 
Thanks!

UPDATE:

Thanks for the helpful suggestions.  I'm using a .yml file for the DB credentials.  I really just need Python to iterate over the .yml file and extract the DB credentials one at a time, so that I can run the script as a loop across all DBs. Here is an example

```
  databases:

  - test_db1: 
      host: testhost
      database: test_database
      user: user1
      password: password1
      account: test_account
      warehouse: test_wh

  - test_db2: 
      host: testhost2
      database: test_database2
      user: user12
      password: password12
      account: test_account2
      warehouse: test_wh2
```

Comment: what is the issue with looping over list of credentials and creating new connection for each one at a time ?

Comment: My first thought is either serverless or container based scripts where you spin up a container for each customer job, and use AWS Secrets Manager to fetch one customer's credentials.  Maybe using SQS for the work queue.  The script doesn't include credentials, and it only has them for one customer at a time.  https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/03/secrets-manager-rotate-credentials-for-documentDB-redshift0/  .  I might be missing many problems with this, but I think it's safer not to mix together customer credentials.

Comment: Your bigger issue will be connectivity. Are all of these databases in _your_ account? Are they all in the same VPC?